# Integrate sin(x)^2 using IBP's Twice

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate $sin(x)^2$ by using Integration-by-parts twice but can't get the right solution. I know there are answers to this particular integral already, but I want to avoid using identities and would really like to know where I made the mistake (or at least why I can't do it this way).
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} sin(x)^2  \quad u = sin(x),\quad u' = cos(x), \quad v = -cos(x),\quad v' = sin(x)$$

$$\\ = sin(x) * (-cos(x))\Biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} -cos(x)*cos(x) \quad u = -cos(x),\quad u' =sin(x), \quad v = sin(x),\quad v' = cos(x)$$

$$=sin(x) * (-cos(x))\Biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - sin(x) * (-cos(x))\Biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} sin(x)^2 \quad \rvert +\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} sin(x)^2$$

$$\\ 2*\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} sin(x)^2=sin(x) * (-cos(x))\Biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - sin(x) * (-cos(x))\Biggr|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

This is how far I have gotten. The right side will always be $0$ because either $sin(0)$ or $cos(\pi/2) = 0$!? However, the correct answer should be $\pi/4$.

Comment: Watch your signs- on the last integral you get positive $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2 x \, dx$ from expanding the negative from $-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (-\cos x)(\cos x)\,dx$ which leads to $0=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Does that mean, by using IBP twice, I am spinning in a circle, getting a true statement (0=0) but never a solution to the integral (meaning I simply HAVE to use identities or similar way to solve this)?

Comment: You have discovered that integration by parts is not much help on this integral. Try the half-angle identities instead.